# PHP Netbeans: xdebug stops on every include() or require()

Tags: php, netbeans, debugging, xdebug

I've just discovered PHP debugging using xdebug integrated in netbeans IDE and I think it's great! how did I live without it? :)

But there's one problem: if I set a breakpoint deep in my code, I have to press "Continue" (F5) several times before I get to a breakpoint, because script stops at every include() and require() functions.

My includes look like that:

```
<?php
    require_once('include/config.inc.php');
    require_once('include/forms.inc.php');
?>
```

Is it a bug, or I can disable this behavior, so my I don't have to press "Continue" several times?

I'm using NetBeans 6.9.1 on ubuntu 9.10

Answer (score 23, accepted):

go to **Configuration > PHP > General** and ***uncheck*** "Stop at First Line"

Approve the changes and try again

every `include`/`require` is a new *"First Line"* ;)

Comment: Thanks! :) I new t was a feature, not bug :)

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Netbeans 8.1 version, here is a slight change in the location where you can find this option. Go to **Tools > Options > PHP >Debugging** tab and ***uncheck*** "Stop at First Line"